# How to extract child key value from an array [PHP]?

Tags: php, arrays

The `[1152]` key is dynamic.

I need to access the child keys `(ex: guid)` but the parent key `[1152]` is dynamic and there is no way for me to know which number is going to be generated.

Is it possible to access `[guid]` without knowing what the number is in the parent key?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes process the first level of the array in a simple foreach and then the inner array specifically like this

```
foreach ($array as $dynamic) {
    foreach ($dynamic as $key=>$val) {

        echo $key . ' = ' . $val;
    }
}
```

Or even more simply

```
foreach ($array as $dynamic) {
    echo $dyanmic['guid'];
}
```

Comment: that inner loop isn't even necessary, `guid` can be accessed like `$dyanmic['guid']`